# What dp resolution do I work with for a universal android app?

Tags: android, imageview, resolution, scaling

I have been developing an android app and currently optimizing the UI for the majority of phones.
I am having a lot of difficulty understanding dp resolution.

What is the resolution in DP I am aiming to design my layouts to? I know android has 4 sizes:

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

but that says at least.
If I am given a phone with 400dp by 800dp and my image views are designed for 640dp by 480dp does android scale it down? If it doesn't then my content looks bad.

Please keep in mind that I don't want to use wrap content to scale my image views because I am pulling my images from a server and I don't know the exact resolution, so the image views will end up all mis-shapen if I use wrap content.

Thank you.

Comment: If you're using Android Studio, you're project will come with folders set for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi folders in the res directory by default. Using these, you can store the same set of images a different sizes to match each resolution and the app will use the correct images based on the resolution of the device.

Answer (score 0):

Check those links:

[screens support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
[dp, dpi, sp...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2025282/1332549)
and this [one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidResourceSelection/article.html)